# How to determine the inputshape of a ANN in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I started to use Keras for ANN and something that I do not really understand is which values to choose for the input_shape parameter of the first layer in an ANN? I know that the number should be equal to the inputs but how can I determine the order and the other value in the vector. For example, here is the code of a Multilayer Perceptron that takes 3 inputs and calculates 1 output

```
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[3,])),
model.add(Dense(20,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='linear'))
```

In this case I use 'input_shape=[3,]'. The 3 comes from the 3 inputs but why do I have a ",]" as the second argument. Here you see on the other hand the code for a recurrent neural network that is used for time series forecasting and that has 6 input features for every timeslot of the time series and calculates 24 outputs:

```
model6 = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 6]),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(24))
])
```

Why do I have here another order with "input_shape=[None, 6]" and not "input_shape=[6, None]" and why do I need here "None" as the first argument and not like in the multilayer perceptron just ",]". Has this something to do with the recurrent neural network such that I always have to use the number of input features as the second argument and 'None' as the first argument.

I read about this in the keras documentation but it is still confusing for me. Can you tell me how to choose those input_shape argument`I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two parts.

1. Why there is a comma in the `[3,]`? In this case you can skip it and just use `[3]`. You can encounter it in the tutorials, because you can pass the tuple as shape as well - `(3,)` and if you skip the comma in the tuple, then it will be just number, not tuple. So, it's just more of a python, not a keras itself. Try this in terminal

```
>>> 3 == (3)
True
>>> 3 == (3,)
False
>>> [3] == [3,]
True
```

The bottom line is that keras in this case expects 1-dimensional objects of size 3.

2. About the recurrent networks. In contrast with fully-connected neural nets, the input to the RNN is two-dimensional. I.e. you have a time series with 10 steps, each defined by 3 numbers, then the shape would be (10, 3). The problem is that you don't know beforehand how many steps you will have - it could be 20, it could be 5. So, you use None as a placeholder to say the keras to expect some dimension there.

You can ask, why we use `None` here and not something else. The reason is numpy has been using similar notations for years. See the example below

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.ones(5)
>>> x.shape
(5,)
>>> x_2 = x[None, :5]
>>> x_2.shape
(1, 5)
```

In this case `None` in index tells  numpy to add a dimension. It's not very transparent thing and could be confusing at first, especially with all the other notation, but you will get used to it.

EDIT

3. Worth mentioning, the number of dimensions of input tensors always will be bigger on one, i.e. 2 dimensions for MLP and 3 for the RNN, because we process data in batches. Thus, the first dimension *always* will be the number of samples.
   Let's look on the examples.

- For MLP input tensor shape could be [128, 3], where the 128 is the number of samples and 3 is number of features. `input_shape=(3,)`
- For RNN input tensor shape could be [128, 30, 3], where the 128 is the number of sample, 30 is sequence length and 3 is number of features. `input_shape=(None, 3)`
- For convolutional NN the inputs will be images and shape like [128, 220, 220, 3], where the 128 is the number of images, 220x220 - size of the image and 3 is number of channels (colors). `input_shape=(220, 220, 3)`

The interesting fact - we asked to specify the input shape not because keras authors are pedants, but because the specific size of the network is depend on it and we need this info during initialization. As batch size doesn't influence the model size, it is omitted by convention. We would probably omitted the sequence length as well, if the RNN was the only architecture, but for consistency with other type of models it is as it is.

Comment: Thanks Kirill for your answer. So can I just always use `[None, numberOfFeaturesPerTimeSlot]` when having a RNN?

Comment: Yes, or if you know the number of step in you data, you can pass it instead of None

Comment: Just to complement a bit, normally in Keras/Tensorflow, the first dimension is the `batch_size` which is useful when managing large datasets. Even if you specify a one-dimension `input_shape` (e.g `(3,)`) internally the network will expect `(batch_size, 3)`

Comment: Yes, and for RNN it would expect (batch_size, number_of_steps, features_count)

Comment: Thanks for your comment jcaliz. Basically the 3 is not the batch size  I specify the batch size somewhere else in the model definition `model.fit(X_input_dataset, Y_output_dataset, epochs=5, batch_size=10, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)` with 10. The (3,) is just the number of input neurons in  the first layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Kirill. I accepted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Hi all, it's me again having a problem understanding the answer about the inputshape for a RNN. In the tutorial they use input_shape=[None, 6] but the input data  (training) does not have 2 but 3 dimension with (43800, 168, 6). So why is there one dimension missing in the input shape? I'd appreciate every further comment.

Comment: It's what @jcaliz talk about earlier. 43800 is basically a number of sequences in the dataset, 168 is length of each sequence and 6 is number of features.

Comment: And another further quesiton. Why is the input_shape of the multilayer perceptron (3,) and not (,3) as in the RNN (the number of features per datapoint is the last dimension? How can I derive the needed dimensionality and the corresponding order in the parameter input_shape for different ANNs? Is it something that I just have to learn (like vocabluaries) or can I somehow derive that?

Comment: Are you sure it was `(,3)` there? Looks like invalid syntax to me

Comment: @KirillFedyanin. Thanks for your answer. I know that the 43800 is the number of sequences in the dataset. But I am wondering why I do not specify it in the insputshape? The inputshape of the training data (43800, 168, 6 looks different than the input shape of the RNN [None, 6]. So the training data is 3 dimensional whereeas the input shape is only 2 dimensional

Comment: @KirillFedyanin: Well a small typo. The input shape is [3,]. But the question is the same: Why [3,] and not [,3] and how can I derive the order?

Comment: `[,3]` is still looks like an invalid syntax to me =). `[3,]` and `(3,)` are both valid and would be treated identically in this case, you can use any.

Comment: As of the your other question, see the part 3 in edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kirill for your answer and effort. I know understand why the first dimension is 'missing' in the input shape. However, I still do not understand the order for the MLP. The input shape is [3,] and not [,3]. But why is it [3,] and not [,3]. I never said it was [,3] it is always [3,] so I do not understand why you keep telling that [,3] is wrong. Yes it is wrong but I have not used it as far as I see it. Still I do not understand why [,3] is wrong in the MLP whereas in the RNN the size of the  features is in the last dimension [None, 6] instead of [6, None] for example?

Comment: Because `[,3]` is incorrect syntax in python. If you asking, why then `[3,]` is correct, I would refer to [why trailing comma is allowed in python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597901). Another thing which could be confusing - `None` is not nothing or space, it's a special object in python.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks a lot Kirill for your tremendous help.